# 1980s Sci Fi Children's stories. Similar to Star Trek

Tags: story-identification

As a young child in the late 1980s or early 1990s, I remember reading at school a series of sci fi illustrated books. However, the books may have been older. The series was similar to Star Trek in appearance. I remember one story about a planet of ant like aliens. One of the characters may have been called something like 'Commander Peck'. 
Can anyone help me identify these stories?
Thank you.

Comment: One of Kirk's predecessors as Enterprise captain was Christopher Pike, who did star in some of the books. Have a look at http://theomegasector.com/index.php?/topic/21008-a-guide-to-the-adventures-of-captain-pike-in-novels-and-comics/  and see if anything looks familiar.

Comment: Do any of these guys look like the aliens? https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Chakuun - or https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Lirin ?

Comment: If they do - https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/One_of_a_Kind ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
However, I am 100% sure it wasn't Star Trek, but looked very similar.
The aliens in one of the stories looked a bit like a cross between Ants and Tholians.